# Need help in defining time complexity of this algorithm (Brent's algorithm for cycle detection)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

so I need help in defining the time complexity for Brent's algorithm for cycle detection. This is the code in question:

```
struct Node* detectCycle(struct Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    struct Node* first_pointer = head;
    struct Node* second_pointer = head->next;
    int power = 1;
    int length = 1;

    while (second_pointer != NULL && second_pointer != first_pointer) {
        if (length == power) {
            power *= 2;
            length = 0;
            first_pointer = second_pointer;
        }
        second_pointer = second_pointer->next;
        ++length;
    }
    if (second_pointer == NULL)
        return NULL;
    first_pointer = second_pointer = head;
    while (length > 0) {
        second_pointer = second_pointer->next;
        --length;
    }
    while (second_pointer != first_pointer) {
        second_pointer = second_pointer->next;
        first_pointer = first_pointer->next;
    }
    return first_pointer;
}
```

On geeks for geeks it says that - Time Complexity: O(m + n) where m is the smallest index of the sequence which is the beginning of a cycle, and n is the cycle’s length.

Now I am unsure how to present or come to a conclusion of this m + n in my calculation of the complexity. When calculating the complexity of the code step by step I would get O(n) and it does seem logical for me that this would be the answer.

I need this for a class and the teacher is very demanding so I don't know if he would accept the O(n) answer.

any help on how to explain how we come to the conclusion of O(m + n) when doing line by line calculation of the time complexity of the algorithm?

thank you in advance

Comment: If the *n* in O(*n*) refers to the cycle length, it's clear that the algorithm cannot be O(*n*), because there might not be a cycle, or it might be a very short cycle following an enormous tail. That is the definition of *n* which you cite; if you suddenly mean something else, you need to make that clear.

Comment: I'm still very new to this, but how I understood the big O notation is that O(n) would mean that a function uses n number of instructions to finish. so I don't understand why O(m + n) would be different from O(n). for example we don't write O(10) but instead use O(1) - so my question is why should this be different?
also when looking at the code which while loop would represent the m and which would represent n? I get completely lost here because there are 3 while loops that can all take different amounts of iterations to finish, how do I write it down and show where I am getting the m and n?

Comment: O(*n*) does indeed mean that something (perhaps the number of instructions executed) will be (proportional to) *n*, but it doesn't define *n*. Similarly, we might write O(*n*²) to indicate that some quantity is proportional to *n*². Often, *n* is used to mean "the size of the problem", which in this case would presumably be the length of the linked list. But when GforG says "O(*m* + *n*) where *m* is something and *n* is something else, they are defining *m* and *n* for the purposes of this analysis, so you have to read it that way...

Comment: In a linked list, *m* + *n* is exactly the total length of the list. So they are really saying that the time complexity of Brent's algorithm is O(*N*) where *N* is the length of the linked list. For whatever reason, --perhaps to simplify the proof-- they chose to break the analysis into two parts, *m* and *n*. That needs to be done with care. Anyway, I'll bet that you have a textbook (perhaps Cormen *et al*) which carefully defines big-O notation; if not, you could try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). But Cormen is easier to follow IMHO.

Comment: what do you think could be the reasoning behind breaking the analysis into two parts? what do we gain by doing this? and also just to say, thank you for your time you have actually helped me a lot.

Comment: I guess it depends on how well your intuitions work. How did you figure out how many times the loop condition `while (second_pointer != NULL && second_pointer != first_pointer)` is repeated before it is false? Certainly, if there is no loop at all, `second_pointer` will be NULL after exactly *N* iterations, but if there is a loop, it will never be  NULL. So then what? If you have an answer which doesn't involve the size of the tail and the size of the loop, great! But most of us will not be able to do better than GfG: the smallest power of 2 greater than each of the tail and the loop.

Comment: Then you need to add one more loop to get a repetition. That sum is somewhere between *N* and 3 *N*.(which is O(*N*) ), but I think the natural way to demonstrate that definitely involves the tail/loop split.

Comment: does the last while loop (getting the first pointer to the beggining of the loop) have the time complexity of m+1? m being the index of the first element of a cycle it would take the pointer m+1 iterations to get to the m element because it is starting at the head?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The second last while advances the loop length and the last while advances the tail length. So between the two loops, every element is touched.